# jquery .click function not working after load

Tags: jquery, html

I have made a **jquery function** which will change status to complete if pending .

The function is executing properly **on first button click** and it is loading my table changing my status to complete.

[image]

But **on second time on button click** it is not reading the function.

Here is my jquery code:

```
 $('a.success_btn').click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var status = "completed";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/vorder.php",
            data:{ o_id: id, o_status: status }, 
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
                $('#all_order').load('orders.php #all_order');
            }
        })  
      });
```

Here:

**a.success_btn** = button class name

**'#all_order'**= my order table div id

**The table is on another php page means** '#all_order' **and it has been included to this page.**

Answer (score 1):

You should [delegate event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) as following:

```
$('#all_order').on('click', 'a.success_btn',function(){
   /*( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)*/
});
```

Comment: actuall #all_order is on another php page , so jquery function will not read this id I guess. Have updated my question.